# PySpark rdd of pandas data frames

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm extracting information of different source files. Each source file corresponds to a given snapshot time of some measurement data. I have a preprocessing function that takes one of these files and outputs a pandas data frame. So I did a spark `sc.wholeTextFiles` call, which gave me a list of all input files, and then I called `map` on it, which provided me with an rdd where each element is a pandas data frame. What would now be the best approach to "reshape" this structure such that I have only one resulting data frame consisting of the concatenated smaller data frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can create spark dataframe. Assuming that these files situated in one location and are delimted you can use spark to create a new dataframe having data from all files.

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("../location/*")
```

After that you can use lot of transformations available in spark. They are a lot similar to pandas, and works on bigdata and even faster than RDD.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, that the files at not CSV's they have to be processed first to get a CSVish format.

Comment: Can you post sample of these files. It would help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: so the files consist of some really specific non-tabular data, which have to be processed before continuing. For this reason, I wrote manually a parser that returns a data frame for a given input file.

Comment: if after parsing there are different dataframes. You can loop over each dataframe and union each df to new spark df. provided they have same columns.

Comment: Okay, but this must happen on the master, right? There is no solution for union multiple data frames on the workers.